# How to bind FormArray to a parent component?

Tags: angular

I have a child component that contains a FormArray.I want to bind this FormArray's values to a form in a parent component. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Lookup ‘ControlValueAccessor’.. that allows you to create a component that acts like a ‘normal’ form input.

Comment: @MikeOne I'm trying to use control value acessor. Should the FormArray be bound to another FormArray in the parent component, or to a FormControl? I'm currently trying to bind it to a FormArray and getting undefined when I submit my form.

Comment: @victorgvargas, where you defined the formArray? in parent or in child?

Comment: @Eliseo the FormArray is defined in the child component

Comment: You dont need to use ControlValueAccessor if the goal is only to access the formArray from the parent. Build the form array in the parent and use an @Input to pass the array to the child. Every changes from the child is going to be seen by the form declared in the parent

Comment: You could, but then you’re missing out on all the build-in Reactive Form goodies :-)

Comment: @victorgvargas - it depends how you want to set it. If there is a formArray in the CVA child, you can probably just use a normal formControl as feed and let the child just set arrays of values on your parent formControl..

Comment: @MikeOne if the child is just a custom input than using controlValueAccessor make sense but if its a formGroup than it gets overly complicated real fast

Comment: @ukn the problem is that my child component should be a picker, and I want to have all the logic of picking features in it, so that it could be reused across the app

Comment: @victorgvargas what do you mean by a picker, are you talking about some kind of typeahead? It looks like you should implement ControlValueAccessor which would allow you to output the value to the parent.